# C# Get Specific Data from Text

Tags: c#, input, extract, analysis

I am still new to C# and its formatting in general, so I may have a hard time explaining what I'm looking for. But is there a method to read in a text file (.txt) and only pull certain lines of data, specifically when the line has more than 8 "," (commas) in the line, and ignore the rest?

Trying to capture data on a control box, and the data it sends out in debug has everything from motor position, velocity, axis, and more. But it also includes data not needed to graph into excel such as extra comments like Motor has stopped, Acknowledge, and so on. Those lines tend to only have 1-3 commas, whereas the data I'd like to extract for analysis is covered in 8+ commas for all the details given.

Thanks for any tips/advice on this or being able to point me in the right directions with the terminology I'm lacking which does what I'm looking for. I've figured out the File.ReadAllText function so far, and I think that's a good start. But not really sure which terms or functions are used to try to express the rest of what I'm needing.

Comment: No, there's no method that will do exactly that. You have to write code that puts the primitive actions that you described into something that accomplishes your specific goal. Then that method will exist.

Comment: So... you've got this idea of using `File.ReadAllText`, and that could be one of those primitives, but since you mentioned "lines", you probably want to read each line separately, as that allows you to consider or discard each one as you go instead of having to analyze a single string containing the entire file's contents.

Comment: That said, this question is not focused enough for this format.

Comment: Read each line (one by one - alternatively, you could call `File.ReadAllLines`, but there's no advantage to using that much memory).  As you read the line, scan it for 8 commas (either by walking through the characters one-by-one or by constructing a _Regex_ - I'd pick doing a character scan if I were you).  If the line matches your condition, _"pull it out"_ (not sure what you want to do from that expression).  If you try this, show some code, someone may respond with some working code.